# How can I view the indexes or another associated value of missing values from a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

If I know that there were missing values in my email_address column, how can I iterate through it and return the indexes or names of the associated missing values?

I used this code but I don't know what's wrong

```
surveydf
surveydf.isnull()
for i in surveydf['email_address']:
    if surveydf.isnull() is True:
        print(surveydf['first_name'])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

identify the rows with nan values:

```
surveydf['email_address'].isna()
```

use that as a mask:

```
surveydf[surveydf['email_address'].isna()]['first_name']
```

create a list out of the 'first_name' column where isna() is True:

```
list(surveydf[surveydf['email_address'].isna()]['first_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a reason why we can put 2 lists next to each other after the DataFrame? It usually doesn't work if I'm trying to create a DataFrame, i.e surveydf['age']['income']

Comment: syntactically, that's called 'chained indexing' and is warned against here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

a dataframe of the two columns can be generated by surrounding the columns you want with 'double brackets':

surveydf[['age','income']]

which is a shortcut version of:

surveydf.loc[['age','income']]

and if you want to use this smaller dataframe, then it's probably a good idea to make a copy of it to avoid 'SettingWithCopyWarning':

smalldf = surveydf.loc[['age','income']].copy()